# How to delete everything after the last semicolon ,in each line?

Tags: notepad++

example :

20160701 09:16;8317.05;8346.35;8308.65;8336.10;252750

20160701 09:17;8336.80;8341.25;8329.95;8329.95;1404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find what: `;[^;]+$`
- Replace with: `;` if you want to keep the last semicolon, else leave empty
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution. :) I was tinkering with it myself, and was considering using (.+?); to search greedy, but this is a far more elegant solution. +1

Comment: @LPChip: Thank you.